# C++ inline array member uniform initialization

Tags: c++

Say that you have a class that has an array member:

```
class A
{
private:
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t arr[10];
public:
    A(uint8_t length, const uint8_t array[]): length(length)
    {
        memcpy(arr, array, length);
    }
};
```

Then you have a global constant object and you want to use uniform initialization like this:

```
const A A_CONST{1,{23}};
```

In this case the compiler gives an error: "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const uint8_t*"

But this works:

```
const uint8_t arr[]={23};
const A A_CONST{1,arr};
```

But then you have an unnecessary global constant "arr" also. I don't understand why the compiler can't cast {23} to const uint8_t* by looking at the constructor. Why is this so and is there a workaround?

Comment: If it suits your use case, you could remove the constructor and then use aggregate initialization (your initialization statement will work)

Comment: `{23}` is not a valid initializer for a pointer (and nor should it be)

Comment: However, it's possible to initialize the array "arr" like in the second example?

Comment: Your last example is correct, yes

Comment: I guess I would have liked to have some more insight on this. To me these initializations look exactly the same. I just don't see why the first initialization fails and the second doesn't. In the second one you just have an extra middle-man variable "arr". I think when the compiler sees the constructor, it should understand that the second uniform initialization parameter {23} is a constant array.

Comment: In the second one you initialize an array with a braced list of elements (fine -- the list elements are copied into the array elements). In the first one you try to initialize a pointer with a braced list of elements (not fine, no obvious meaning)

Comment: Both are pointers, right? Pointers to a constant array of numbers? I dunno. This "uniform" initialization doesn't seem very "uniform".

Comment: no, one is an array and one is a pointer

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you defined, is equivalent to

```
A(uint8_t length, const uint8_t *array)
```

This is, what the compiler is trying to tell.

To have an initialization as in your example, you must use either another type, or a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), e.g.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

A(const std::initializer_list<uint8_t> array)
    : length(array.size())
{
    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), arr);
}
```

---

Apart from that, don't use plain arrays or (length, pointer) arguments. Better use modern types like `std::array` or `std::vector`, this is less error prone and you get this kind of initialization for free.

Comment: I would use std::vector, but this is an embedded system and I'm trying to minimize the code footprint. But that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use an array (instead of `std::vector`) you can use this example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class A
{
private:
  static const uint8_t MAX_LENGTH = 10;
  uint8_t length;
  uint8_t arr[MAX_LENGTH];
public:
  A(uint8_t _length, const uint8_t array[]): length(_length)
  {
    if (length > MAX_LENGTH) { // to prevent copying out of memory
      length = MAX_LENGTH;
    }
    std::memcpy(arr, array, length);
  }
  A(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> l): length(l.size())
  {
    if (length > MAX_LENGTH) { // to prevent copying out of memory
      length = MAX_LENGTH;
    }
    std::initializer_list<uint8_t>::iterator it = l.begin();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; (i < length) || (it == l.end()); ++i, ++it) {
      arr[i] = *it;
    }
  }
  uint8_t printAllForExample() const {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      std::cout << (int)arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  uint8_t getLengthForExample() const {
     return length;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "A_CONST_1:" << std::endl;
  const A A_CONST_1{23};
  A_CONST_1.printAllForExample();

  std::cout << "A_CONST_2:" << std::endl;
  const A A_CONST_2{};
  std::cout << (int)A_CONST_2.getLengthForExample() << std::endl;
  A_CONST_2.printAllForExample();

  std::cout << "A_CONST_3:" << std::endl;
  const A A_CONST_3{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::cout << (int)A_CONST_3.getLengthForExample() << std::endl;
  A_CONST_3.printAllForExample();

  std::cout << "A_CONST_4:" << std::endl;
  const A A_CONST_4{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
  std::cout << (int)A_CONST_4.getLengthForExample() << std::endl;
  A_CONST_4.printAllForExample();

  uint8_t data[] = {30,40,50};
  std::cout << "A_CONST_5:" << std::endl;
  const A A_CONST_5(3, data);
  std::cout << (int)A_CONST_5.getLengthForExample() << std::endl;
  A_CONST_5.printAllForExample();
  return 0;
}
```